# Поиск купона в базе данных по введённой дате

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, vue.js, axios

Нужно отправить на сервер дату для поиска купона по введённой дате. Дата не идёт в PHP файл (при выводе выдаёт пустую строку).

Форма, написанная на Vue.js:

```
<form method="post" class="p-coupon__time" @submit.prevent="findCoupon()">
   <input type="date" name="picker" v-model="datePicker" title="Дата" required>
   <button class="p-coupon__button-settings" type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Сама функция findCoupon:

```
axios.post('/dist/coupon/getCouponDate.php')
   .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.coupons = response.data;
        if ( this.coupons == null ) {
          this.sold = true
        } else {
          this.soldDate = true;
          this.howMuchCoupon = this.coupons[0].number;
          console.log(this.howMuchCoupon)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

PHP файл:

```
$datePicker = $_POST['picker'];
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$link -> set_charset('utf-8');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE `date` = '$datePicker'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$link -> close();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
 $rows[] = $row;
}
echo $datePicker; // Тест для вывода значения из input
echo json_encode($rows); // То что должно быть
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ:

```
<form method="post" class="p-coupon__time" @submit.prevent="findCoupon()" ref="datePickerKeker">
  <input type="date" name="picker" v-model="datePicker" title="Дата" required>
  <button class="p-coupon__button-settings" type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Js:

```
axios.post('/dist/coupon/getCouponDate.php', new FormData(this.$refs.datePickerKeker))
```

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте вторым параметром в axios.post(url, **obj**) объект.
Например:

```
axios.post(
    '/dist/coupon/getCouponDate.php', 
    JSON.stringify({"picker":'DATE'})
).then(response => { ... }
```

И посмотрите что приходит в $_POST;
Или $body = file_get_contents('php://input');

```
"SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE date = '$datePicker';"
```

Comment: смотрел $_POST. Пустая строка приходит. Толк есть только от $body = file_get_contents('php://input'). В запросе приходит дата введённая, но когда  я это делаю вставляю в запрос SQL,то также прилетает null

Comment: Попробуйте добавить вывод ошибок.

Comment: увы, не сильно шарю в php. Не мог бы подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: Измените запрос, я добавил в ответ. Возможно поможет. И http://www.php.su/mysqli_error()

Answer (score 0):

Дк вы ее и не отправляете на сервер.
`POST-` параметры передаются так:
`axios.post('url', {picker: this.datePicker})`